# Drawing tetrahedron in MATLAB R2011a

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure

I want to draw tetrahedron in MATLAB. How can I do this?

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Do you at least know the coordinates of its vertices?

Comment: I google it and I found in mathworks.com that in MATLAB R2012a exist a method for doing this. but in MATLAB R2011a there isn't such a method.

Comment: you can do it - you just might need to work a little harder. Do you have the coordinates of the vertices?

Comment: yes, with these coordinates, how can I drew it?

Comment: @user559096 Did it work for you???

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
X = [x1 x2 x3 x4]';
Y = [y1 y2 y3 y4]';
Z = [z1 z2 z3 z4]';    
T = [1 2 3; 1 2 4; 2 3 4; 1 3 4];    
trimesh(T,X,Y,Z);
```

and see if it works. The values x1 y1 and z1 are the respective x y x coordinate of vertex 1 (similarly for the other vertices). I dont have MATLAB access right now so I have modified this from my octagon generator code. You might need to play with the vertices order to get it to work, but this approach will enable you to plot your tetrahedron

Edit: another option is `trisurf` in place of `trimesh` to get surface rather than wireframe

Answer (score 0):

```
    % Draws tetrahedron inscribed in sphere of radius 1
    function draw_regular_tetrahedron(T)

        T = 1/hypot(1, sqrt(2)/2)*T; % scale to fit in unit sphere

        z = 1/sqrt(2);
        S.Vertices = (T*[1,0,-z;-1,0,-z;0,1,z;0,-1,z]')';
        S.Faces = [1,3,4;2,3,4;1,2,3;1,2,4];
        S.FaceVertexCData = [ 1 ];
        S.FaceColor = 'flat';
        S.EdgeColor = 'green';
        p = patch(S);
        alpha(p, 0.5);
    end

>> ps_5_2.draw_regular_tetrahedron(eye(3))
>> ps_5_2.draw_regular_tetrahedron(eye(3)*5)
```

[image]